# web3.js - cannot interact with smart contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, json-rpc

I want to write a simple js script. I follow many tutorial available from Youtube, forums and website but i seem that i cannot interact from the smart contract. i can interact it from remix. btw the smart contract is deployed on my private network.

```
Web3 = require('web3');

console.log("Hi blinkExample")
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://192.168.100.130:8043'));

web3.eth.getAccounts()
.then(console.log);
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
var contractAddress = '0x6b9781fe8b355965a7ce99f58b918f711ab5fe1e';
var abi = [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "theData",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setData",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "name": "data",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "blinkEvent",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getData",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "retData",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "myData",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];

var blinkContract = web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
var data = blinkContract.getData;
console.log('value is' + data);

var event2 = blinkContract.blinkEvent(function(error, result){
    if (!error){
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

the console will show account list just fine but displays "value is undefined" then crash for the blinkEvent with typeError: blinkContract.blinkEvent is not a function. The value should be 12 which I set using remix.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on web3 v1.x, change this:

```
var blinkContract = web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
var data = blinkContract.getData;
console.log('value is' + data);
```

To this:

```
var blinkContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
blinkContract.methods.getData().call().then(function(data) {
    console.log('value is' + data);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So its they changed it? I am a noob at js so it is very confusing. I am currently away from my pc. I will try asap. Thank you.